What is the technical explanation of this satellite photography of an airplane moving fast
This screenshot was taken on Apple Maps on August 2024 at this location :
45,18727° N, 0,34439° W
We can see "2 airplanes".

The first is the white one. RGB colors seems separated. I understand that the sensor captures colors sequentially : Red, then Green, then Blue. As the plane is moving fast during the shot, colors appears shifted in the direction of the move. This question has an awnser to this point.

The second airplane though is myterious to me. It is darker and surprinsingly sharp. How can the focus point be on the ground and at the same time tens of kilometers above ? Why is there a "second plane" ? Is this a specificity of satellite photography ?




This question is similar to: Why does this satellite image of an airplane in motion show red, green, and blue bands with strange artifacts?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Indeed, this thread anwsers the first point of my question. But the second point remains. I added the link.

After reading the answer to the linked question: Since the colours of the second plane match mostly with the ground below, could it be that this is what the greyscale sensor of the satellite recorded (probably a bit after the red/green/blue images)?

You are right, I didn't notice the green on the wing, it could match the color of trees around. But why the camera would record gray scale in addition to RGB ?

While I am curious to see the answer, you might get better answers on the Space or Earth sciences SEs where satellite imaging would be among their core expertise.  Especially as the location could narrow down the actual satellite used for the image and give an answer that relates to the actual sensors in use.

Am on mobile so writing an answer is a bit cumbersome, but this link likely has the required info https://www.gearthblog.com/blog/archives/2015/03/planes-flight-rainbow-effect.html

@David If you compare the level of detail captured in the colour planes and the greyscale you can see the difference between resolution and contrast.

Also related: Red-channel rolling shutter in google maps?


The second airplane though is myterious to me. It is darker and surprinsingly sharp

This image has almost certainly been pansharpened. The process of pansharpening combines intensity taken from a high-resolution image having a single channel, with hue taken from a lower-resolution image having multiple channels, to produce an image with more information than either of its inputs alone.
Notice in particular that the sharp airplane image is colored in brown and green — the colors of the field, path, and trees below it. I don't know why it's so dark, but I'd guess that the particular algorithm used refrains from making an output pixel much brighter than the input color was, to avoid amplifying noise from dark pixels when edges don't perfectly align.

The cameras used on satellites uses different techniques. Multiple shots are taken in quick suspension, each imaging at different wavelengths of light. Likely, one exposure captures the image in monochrome followed by multiple exposures, each taken through colored filters imposed atop the camera lens. Some shots could be in the infrared region to penetrate cloud cover. These image a heat signature and convert it to false colors. The final image is likely a composite image.
Our ordinary digital cameras make three exposures via red, green and blue filters. The three images are taken simultaneously. The satellite camera need not image these different wavelengths simultaneously.
